# How to make UI Automation click a button with no id?

Tags: c#, user-interface, ui-automation, white-framework

Im using TestStack.White as a UI Automation for c# and I have ran into a problem.

I need to click a save as button but Visual UI tells me it doesnt have a AutomationId. 
[image]

My current code is

```
Application manager = Application.Launch("PATH");
Window mainWindow = manager.GetWindow("ReportViewer");
mainWindow.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Save As")).Click();
```

and I get a error saying it cannot find the button

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Is there a `ByName` criteria?

Comment: No theres not its strange.

Comment: Try to find a parent with an ID an iterate children until you find the right one.

Comment: I just ended up using a button with a id nearby and using the tab key to navagate

Comment: @nickivey - If you're happy with your answer, please answer it yourself so it's closed